# How to find an element in an array with elasticsearch

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I have one array like `["a", "b", "c"]` in my DB (mysql) and I want to get all those rows that include `"a"`. How can I do that with elasticSearch and Go?

My code is the following:

```
query.Must(elastic.NewTermsQuery("Visibility",[]string{"a"}))
```

This doesn't work and I couldn't find anything on internet about this, until now. What do you think I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the `mapping` of the index and the sample `document` ?
the terms query should work for the array.

The query you are building in Go should work.
You don't even need `must` unless you have another query.

```
{
 "query" :{
    "terms" : {
       "visibility": ["a"]  
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have one field in the DB `Visibility` which is `[]string` type. Here I store some locale like "en" "pl" etc. I receive one string from frontend i I need to get all those rows that contains this locale. I am really new in golang so sorry if I am not very clear. As I said the DB is mysql and it shows me the elements like `en,pl,ro,cz`. Have I done something wrong? for example the type of visibility? Cannot figure out

Comment: You are querying elasticsearch right ?, Not sure how mysql is involved here. could you paste a sample document from elasticsearch index which you are trying to query ?

Comment: what do you mean with a document from elasticsearch index?